# Powershell - Merge values from two variables using hashtable

Tags: powershell

**Sample Code::-**

```
$hash = $null
$hash = @{}

1..8 | ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName "192.168.1.$_" -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue") {
        try{
                
            $proc = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName "192.168.1.$_" -ErrorAction Stop |
            select CSName,caption

                    foreach ($p in $proc)
                        {
                            $hash.add($p.csname,$p.caption)
                        }
            }
        catch{
            write-warning "Unable to get WMI info from '192.168.1.$_'" |
            out-file "results.txt" -append
        }
    }
    else {
        write-warning "Unable to connect to '192.168.1.$_'" |
        out-file "results.txt" -append
    }
}

$hash
```

**Result::**

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                           
----                           -----                                                                                                                                           
DC                             Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard                                                                                                          
SCCMCB                         Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard                                                                                                          
WIN1020H2                      Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation
```

**DESIRED Result should include "IP" as well::**

```
Name            IP                            Value                                                                                                                                           
----                                         -----                                                                                                                                           
DC              192.168.1.3               Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard                                                                                                          
SCCMCB          192.168.1.5               Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard                                                                                                          
WIN1020H2       192.168.1.7               Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why a hash and not a PsObject?
The code could be simplified by removing the `foreach($p in $proc)` and simply return the object straight away including a calculated property 'IP'

```
$result = 1..8 | ForEach-Object {
    $ip = "192.168.1.$_"
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $ip -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue") {
        try{
            # nowadays you should be using Get-CimInstance instead of Get-WmiObject
            # see https://blog.ipswitch.com/get-ciminstance-vs-get-wmiobject-whats-the-difference
            Get-WmiObject -Class  Win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $ip -ErrorAction Stop |
            Select-Object CSName, @{Name = 'IP'; Expression = {$ip}}, Caption
        }
        catch{
            Write-Warning "Unable to get WMI info from '$ip'"
            "Unable to get WMI info from '$ip'" | Add-Content -Path "results.txt"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Unable to connect to '$ip'"
        "Unable to connect to '$ip'" | Add-Content -Path "results.txt"
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as structured CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\ComputerInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

P.S. If you would like to also change the property name `CSName`, you can use a calculated property for that too like:

```
Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.CSName}}, @{Name = 'IP'; Expression = {$ip}}, Caption
```

Comment: All working well with WMIObject.                                                                                                                                          
&                                                                                                                                        Getting Error message if i use CIMInstance.                                                                          
Get-CimInstance : The WinRM client cannot process the request.

Comment: @Varun In that case use `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_operatingsystem`.. Changed it back to use old WMI for you.